# why interface is important in creating RMI application?

Tags: java, interface, chat, rmi

When we create RMI application in java do we have to create an interface first?
Is an interface compulsory? Can we create RMI application without creating an interface?
If not then why is the interface compulsory? What is the function of it?
If anyone has code of Chatting in RMI without using remote interface then could you send that code to me?

Comment: There is the notion of Java `interface` type. There is also the notion of an interface as a front to interact with. Don't confuse them

Comment: @Shikhil : you got me confused as well, so I stay what Sotirios sad

Comment: can we create RMI chatting without creating remote interface?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how it could be done without using an interface.  Perhaps there is a simple way to do it and no-one has thought of it yet ;) What would the client be calling exactly given it cannot call the implementation directly?

Comment: Just for the record: Interface = Service Contract. You don't access an implementation, you have a service provider that sends you *which* services can you consume.

Comment: ok thanx @PeterLawrey and Gamb.It means we have to create interface.Thnx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When we create RMI application in java do we have to create an interface first?

Yes.

> Is an interface compulsory?

That's the same question, and the answer is also the same. Yes.

> Can we create RMI application without creating an interface?

That's the same question for a third time, and the answer is still the same, although in the negative this time as you reversed your question.

> If not then why is the interface compulsory?

Because that's how they designed it. If you didn't have a remote interface, you wouldn't have any API to call your remote methods with at the client.

> What is the function of it?

That's the same question again, and the answer is also the same.

> If anyone has code of Chatting in RMI without using remote interface then could you send that code to me?

That's not a proper request for this site. If there is such code, which there isn't, and can't be, it should be posted here as an answer. This is not a private help desk.

Answer (score 0):

RMI is about a client machine communicating with a server machine in such a special way that it seems from the programmer's perspective that you are invoking methods of an object which resides on the server.

Clearly, there is some network communicating "magic" going on behind the scenes, and the central programming paradigm which enables this separation of the "behind the scenes" action and the perception you get by reading client code is, well, `interface`.

From this line of reasoning you should be able to convince yourself that you not only cannot get around defining an `interface`, it is in fact the *central* concept around which everything else is built.

Comment: ok means we need something in between both server and client.One can invoke method of other

Comment: Yes, and this *in between* is handled by the RMI technology for you, such that there is an object on the client side which implements the interface you have defined so that the method invocations are sent over the wire to the server.